# MediaRecorder audio volume is very low

Tags: audio, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I am trying to record video using `MediaRecorder` using the following settings:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

After recording is complete, the recorded video volume is very low. What can be settings of `MediaRecorder` for the audio volume boost? Or can we control the audio gain using `MediaRecorder`?

Comment: Did you fix this?